# combining mechanize browser with selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, mechanize

I had to use mechanize to write a login script in python and make some changes in the HTML, now using the mechanize.Browser() I attained the below HTML, now I wish to search and click the button "Delete" and is in a div which I could not do with mechanize.

I browsed the internet and found that selenium can be used to click this button. But all the examples make an instance of firefox browser. How can I make selenium continue what I did with mechanize first.

```
<div class="modal-buttons"><input type="button" onclick="Modal.vars.action(); return Modal.hide(event);" value="Delete" class="freshbutton-blue"><input onclick="Modal.hide(event)" type="button" name="cancel delete" value="Cancel" class="freshbutton"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to instantiate a webdriver instance from HTML source code, atleast from what I see in the selenium API. Selenium is a tool to test real user actions/interactions with a website and that is why Selenium opens a browser(maintains cookies, sessions, renders javascript) and emulate user actions a real user would perform.